# to.be.reverted function showing invalid chai property

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, chai, assert

```
it("money",async()=>{
        console.log(await instance.hasRole("0xc5d48d6799b0d7d7cdfebe6afd6fac6dff6746359d2e02d434f8172e9a93fe97",accounts[8])); 
        console.log(await instance.set_blacklisted(accounts[8],{from:accounts[0]})); 
        console.log(await instance.hasRole.call("0xc5d48d6799b0d7d7cdfebe6afd6fac6dff6746359d2e02d434f8172e9a93fe97",accounts[8])); 
        await instance.sendTransaction({from:accounts[1],value:100000000000000000});
        await expect(instance.sendTransaction({from:accounts[8],value:100000000000000000})).to.be.reverted;
    })
```

Accounts[8] should give a revert but when i try to  `to.be. reverted;` function in `expect()` it shows

```
 Error: Invalid Chai property: reverted
      at Context.<anonymous> (crowdsale_beta.test.js:28:98)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Have you tried `to.be.rejected`

Comment: what is instance? a contract instance or a signer? are you sure  that a contract instance can call sendTransaction ?

Comment: if you are trying to send a transaction from accounts 8 to the contract then try probably (accounts[8]). sendTransaction({to: instance.address, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")})

Comment: https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html?highlight=.reverted#change-ether-balance

Comment: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/997